# Does Coruscant still have an affiliation with the New Republic?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

When the Hosnian System was eradicated in Episode VII, there was no mention of any other New Republic systems still intact. In the other canon material it is obvious that the Resistance was mainly focused on the capital of the New Republic, but wouldn't Coruscant also have to be a member after having the Senate relocated?

Answer (score 2):

### Probably, but uncertain

Throughout the *Bloodline* canon novel, New Republic senators from Coruscant are mentioned:

> “Have you no faith in the soldiers of the New Republic, Senator
>   Sindian?” This objection actually came from another Centrist, Senator
>   Arbo, one of the war hawks of Coruscant. “Senator Organa will travel
>   with an entire squadron of guards to protect her at all times. Do not
>   doubt their ability or their valor!”
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Bloodline*</sub>
>
> ---
>
> “Isn’t it obvious?” said Orris Madmund, the junior senator from
>   Coruscant, as he walked along the halls of the main Senate building
>   beside Ransolm Casterfo. “Yesterday’s bombing was the Populists’
>   work.”
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Bloodline*</sub>

Certainly Coruscant was a member of the New Republic *at that time*.

However, this was some time prior to the formation of the First Order. Most of the senators from Coruscant are mentioned as being Centrists. Many Centrist worlds later broke away to form the First Order, so it is possible that Coruscant did the same.

> It would take a few months to put events in motion. They needed a firm
>   structure before proceeding. But soon, the Centrist worlds would leave
>   the New Republic, tearing themselves from the mire of the Senate’s
>   inaction to create and support the First Order. Her heart sang merely
>   thinking of it.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Bloodline*</sub>

This, however, seems unlikely: Coruscant was one of the more central planets of the Republic, and despite the many Centrists among its Senators, would have little to gain from leaving the Republic.